# perl get elements from array, nested

Tags: perl, dbi

I am using perl DBI module to get data back from database in array format. The code I have so far looks like this:

```
$rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("show SELECT * FROM table SAMPLE 3");
foreach $h (@$rows) {
  foreach $x (@$h) {
    printf "%s\n", $x;
  }
}
```

After I put a break in debug mode I see my data like this: (the $h)

---

```
 0 ARRAY(0x32c40f8)
   0 "CREATE SET TABLE (my contents....)
```

---

My questions are: 1. How do I know how big is the array and
 2. How do I print all the contents that is I want - "CREATE SET TABLE (my contents....)
 Please someone shed some idea and Thank you...

Comment: I tried, number of row and it is 1. How do I get the length? It's not horizontal array rather vertical, and out put looks like this: <p> 0 
  0 ARRAY(0x32c40f8) 
    0 "CREATE SET TABLE (my contents....)
    <\p>

Comment: I think it is reference of referenced context. Sorry I am not able to format the result set properly but it is like a stair with 3 steps below: 0 (nothing after) first line, then  ARRAY(0x32c40f8) (on the second line, shifted two space to right) and finally my content on the 3rd line but shifted 3 space to the right.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the number of elements in an array to which you have a reference? `@$ref` in scalar context.

Comment: @ ikegami I am asking how do I print the contents that is on the 3rd line and shifted to 3 spaces and it consist of multiple lines after. thanks!

Comment: You already are.

Comment: Problem is, it is printing only last line of the array not the beginning of my contents for that reference....

Comment: You are mistaken. It's printing every field of every row of the resultset.

Comment: OK, may be I am missing something. When I debug it, and stop right after that fetch loop, I see the variable $h does have my content containing multiple lines, however when I run it, I just see 1 line.

Comment: You keep talking about lines, but there are no lines, just rows and fields.

Comment: OK so how do I print all rows and all fields (just contents and not the array)? Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about printing _debugger_'s output? If not, and you want to print `$rows` then you _are doing that_ -- perhaps replace that unneeded `printf` with `say $x;` (you may need to add `use feature 'say';` at the top of your program)

Comment: You probably want to remove `show` from your SQL

Comment: [`use Data::Dumper;`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) and `print Dumper($x);` makes things much clearer in most cases.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation in your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Good indentation is an important tool in understanding a piece of code. If you're asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper $rows` to make sure you're getting what you expect from `selectall_arrayref`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured out. Since it was array element [0], all I had to do is assign this to a variable and then do the split.  Hope this helps. Thanks!

```
 $st= $h->[0];
 @lines = split/,/,$st;
```

Answer (score -1):

**try**

```
use DDP;

my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("show SELECT * FROM table SAMPLE 3");
my $len = @$rows;
p $len;
foreach $h (@$rows) {
    p $h;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mathew, the above code printed lenth=1 and I did get the complete last line on the result along with some other line concatenated. Very odd still did not dump the complete array contents. Any other idea?

Comment: @Borodin the "Show" actually is part of the command that I am running. The SELECT works fine and returns results but the Show actually pulls the DDL related to that select is involved. This is a Teradata specific command.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to follow up on this. When I put a break point and tried to see what's on the $h, it shows all the contents that is complete array.  However when the above code tried to print it just print the last line also the length shows 1. Not understanding why.... any other thoughts?